# correct procedure to convert string date (using jquery datepicker ) to date time in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I have faced issues while inserting date from c# to SQL Server. What is the correct method to insert date from c# to a column which is in DateTime to SQL Server.

Currently my method is to convert the string date to DateTime format and then insert into database.

```
Datetime dt = Convert.ToDateTime(txtDate.Text.Trim());
```

Doing so I have come across an error where the current system date conflicts with the newly converted date. What is the correct way to insert string date into database ?

Comment: Where exactly is your "conflict"? In converting the string to `DateTime`, or in inserting the `DateTime` to the database? If latter, show us your code that does the INSERT.

Comment: I have update the question and the error took when the jquery datetime format(say mm/dd/yyyy) conflicts with the system datetime format(say dd/mm/yyyy)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [SqlParameter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparameter.aspx) and form a [parameterized query](http://blog.divergencehosting.com/2009/04/09/using-parameters-parameterized-queries-database-interactions-cshar-vbnet/). In that manner you will pass the .Net DateTime object to SQL Server.

Something like:

```
using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("yourconnectionstring"))
using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT into yourTable([DateCol]) VALUES (@pDate)", con))
{
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pDate", DateTime.Now);
    con.Open();
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

For your question:

> What is the correct way to insert string date into database ?

**Don't.** Instead convert the date string to `DateTime` object and then insert it into the database using parameterized query.

For your comment:

> how will you convert string date(using jquery datepicker) to datetime
>   format?

You can use `DateTime.ParseExact` for the format for your datetime picker and convert the string into DateTime object.

For example if your DateTime picker format is: `mm/dd/yyyy` then you can try:

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact(dateString, "mm/dd/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Comment: I think you have gone too far ahead.My question is how will you convert string date(using jquery datepicker) to datetime format?

Comment: @Kannan, `using jquery date picker` - that is very important info but missing from the question. :)

Comment: Thank you very much.This was what i was looking for.can u explain what does 'CultureInfo.InvariantCulture'  do ??

Answer (score 0):

Create a query with parameters like this

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand ("insert into T (...) values (@d",db);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@d",Convert.ToDateTime(txtDate.Text.Trim());
//...
```